# Will R take advantage of 64GB memory on Mac Pro running OSX?

Tags: r, macos

I've been using R 3.1.2 on an early-2014 13" MacBook Air with 8GB and 1.7GHz Intel Core I7, running Mavericks OSX.

Recently, I've started to work with substantially larger data frames (2+ million rows and 500+ columns) and I am running into performance issues. In Activity Monitor, I'm seeing virtual memory sizes of 64GB, 32GB paging files, etc. and the "memory pressure" indicator is red.

Can I use the "throw more hardware" at this problem? Since the MacBook Air tops out at 8GB physical memory, I was thinking about buying a Mac Pro with 64GB memory. Before I spend the $5K+, I wanted to ask if there are any inherent limitations in R other than the ones that I've read about here: [R Memory Limits](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) or if anyone who has a Mac Pro has experienced any issues running R/RStudio on it.  I've searched using Google and haven't come up with anything specific about running R on a Mac Pro.

Note that I realize I'll still be using 1 CPU core unless I rewrite my code. I'm just trying to solve the memory problem first.

Comment: Take a look at the `doParallel` package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf) for registering multiple cores within your `R` script.

Comment: $5K can buy quite a bit of AWS compute power. I have a fully maxed out Mac Pro and end up having to use the parallel options with R and have switched what I can to Spark on it. I also make use of VMs on the machine, but for different workflows. Without knowing what you do it's hard to help, though. You might benefit greatly from just switching to PostgreSQL for your data frame storage as `dplyr` can tell it to munging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several thoughts:

1) Its a lot more cost effective to use a cloud service like https://www.dominodatalab.com (not affiliated). Amazon AWS would also work, the benefit of domino is that it takes the work out of managing the environment so you can focus on the data science.

2) You might want to redesign your processing pipeline so that not all your data needs to be loaded in memory at the same time (soon you will find you need 128 GB, then what). Read up on memory mapping, using databases, separating your pipeline into several steps that can be executed independent of each other, etc (googling brought up http://user2007.org/program/presentations/adler.pdf). Running out of memory is a common problem when working with real life datasets, throwing more hardware at the problem is not always your best option (though sometimes it really can't be avoided).

Comment: I am drawn by the lure of having a hardware solution onsite where I could run RStudio locally instead of via a browser to a cloud based compute instance. However, the cloud solution is more scalable as you point out and I can access it from anywhere, instead of only from the office.